# Need an idea to design DB for clinic appointment scheduling: "A doctor is working in multiple clinics in different timings"

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

currently im working on database design(in MySQL) for clinic appointment scheduling.

**I strucked at the Situation:**

If a doctor works in different Clinics/Hospitals in different timings.

**Ex:**

1. Doctor-A attends Clinic-A at 10am - 12am, Clinic-B at 2pm - 4pm on Monday to Thursday.
2. Doctor-A attends Clinic-A at 9am - 11am, Clinic-B at 3pm - 5pm on Friday and Saturday.
3. Doctor-A does not work on Sundays.

How to design this concept.

**My Work**

```
    tbl_doct
    --------
    id
    name
    email
    psw
```

-

```
    tbl_doct_specialization
    ------------------------
    id
    doct_id
    specialization
    experience
```

-

```
    tbl_clinic
    ----------
    id
    name
    phone
    city
    area
    address
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating at table like this

```
tbl_dctr_clnc_schdl
--------------------

dayname
start_time 
end_time  
clinic_id
doct_id
```